# Julia I can't make a streamplot with my own function of data

Tags: plot, julia

I'm doing my dissertetion and I need to make a streamplot with the velocities matrix.
I have resolved Navier-stokes equations and I have one matrix of u-velocity 19x67 and other matrix of v-velocity 19x67.

To obtain a continuos function I have done a bilinear interpolation but I have problem with the plotting.

I don't know if I explain myself very well but y let you the code.

```
#BILINEAR INTERPOLATION#

X=2
Y=0.67
x_pos=findlast(x->x<X, x)
y_pos=findlast(x->x<Y, y)

x1=((x_pos-1))*Dx
x2=(x_pos)*Dx
y1=((y_pos-1)-0.5)*Dy
y2=(y_pos-0.5)*Dy

u1=u[y_pos-1,x_pos-1]
u2=u[y_pos-1,x_pos]
u3=u[y_pos,x_pos-1]
u4=u[y_pos,x_pos]

u_int(Y,X)=(1/(Dx*Dy))*((x2.-X).*(y2.-Y).*u1+(X.-x1).*(y2.-Y).*u2+(x2.-X).*(Y.-y1).*u3+(X.-x1).*(Y.-y1).*u4)

xx1=((x_pos-1)-0.5)*Dx
xx2=(x_pos-0.5)*Dx
yy1=((y_pos-1))*Dy
yy2=(y_pos)*Dy

v1=v[y_pos-1,x_pos-1]
v2=v[y_pos-1,x_pos]
v3=v[y_pos,x_pos-1]
v4=v[y_pos,x_pos]

v_int(Y,X)=(1/(Dx*Dy))*((x2-X)*(y2-Y)*v1+(X-x1)*(y2-Y)*v2+(x2-X)*(Y-y1)*v3+(X-x1)*(Y-y1)*v4)

#PLOT#

function stream(Y,X)
  u_c=u_int(Y,X)
  v_c=v_int(Y,X)
  
  return u_c,v_c  
end

using CairoMakie

let
    
    fig = Figure(resolution = (600, 400))
    ax = Axis(fig[1, 1], xlabel = "x", ylabel = "y", backgroundcolor = :black)
    streamplot!(ax, stream, -2 .. 4, -2 .. 2, colormap = Reverse(:plasma),
        gridsize = (32, 32), arrow_size = 10)
    display(fig)
end;
```

Any solution?
If you know other method with other package, pls tell me.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, please make sure your code is copy-pastable (here your `x` is undefined for example).

Comment: Your function should take in and return `x::Point2f`, that might be the problem.  Also the order should be x, y not y, x

Comment: @BenoitPasquier Sorry, I missed. `xlength=4;  ylength=1;   nx=65;  ny=17;    x=LinRange(0,xlength,nx+2::Integer);   y=LinRange(0,ylength,ny+2::Integer)` and the error     `ERROR: Function passed to streamplot must return Point2 or Point3`

Comment: Probably the error is the Point2f, how @AnshulSinghvi said me, but I dont know how to resolve

Comment: Here is a rewritten version of the stream function in one line: `stream(xy::Point2f) = Point2f(u_int(xy[2], xy[1]), v_int(xy[2], xy[1]))`.  Hopefully this makes it clearer @mitaiden.